# Flask / Python Queue for more (parallel) users

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, flask, queue

i need help with Python Queue for more (pareallel) users.

I make webapp, based on Flask, for processing relative lot of data. This processing works fine in parallel threads, but i need percentage information about processing (progressbar).

Percentage values i created on Python Queue and works great, but of course, when two (or more) users start processing, queues are mixed.

Is possible use maybe parallel queues or something like separate queues?

I tried use:

```
queues = {}
queues['user.id'] = Queue()
```

but i think, that is not best practice for this situation.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: check out gunicorn (http://gunicorn.org/ ) or apache mod-wsgi server. Use these servers to host your flask application, they have parallel requests support, security and many other features built-in

Comment: If you are processing a lot of work I would suggest a worker queue like Celery.